# How many total digits are written?

Tags: combinatorics

> In Triangleland, numbers must be written as sums of consecutive integers, starting with $1$, with at most one integer used twice. For example, $12$ must be written as $1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 4$, which uses five digits. When all the integers $1$ through $21$ are listed in Triangleland, how many total digits are written?

I could only think of using brute forcee and listing out all of the numbers, but that would take a while. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If $t_n$ is the $n$-th triangular number, all the numbers $t_n+1$ through $t_{n+1}$ are written as a sum of exactly $n+1$ consecutive numbers with at most one of them written twice:

$$t_n + 1 = 1 + \mathbf{1} + \ldots + n$$  $$t_n + 2 = 1 + 2 + \mathbf{2} + \ldots + n$$ $$t_n + 3 = 1 + 2 + 3 + \mathbf{3} +\ldots + n$$
$$\cdots$$

In general, 
$$t_n + k = 1 + \ldots + (k-1) + k + \mathbf{k} + (k+1) + \ldots + n.$$

And finally 
$$t_{n+1} = 1 + \ldots + n + \mathbf{(n+1)}$$

This means that the first number uses one number, the next two use each two, and so forth. Since $21 = t_6$, then you use $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \ldots + 6^2 = 91$ numbers.

To prove that the descomposition is unique, consider this:

Let $T_n = 1 + 2 + \ldots + n$ (you can see that $T_n$ is in fact a descomposition of $t_n$). Any descomposition of any positive integer must be of the form $T_n + a$ where $a = 1,\ldots (n+1)$ for some $n$. That is because we must start with $1$, the numbers must be consecutive and we can repeat at most one.

If $t_N < k \leq t_{N+1}$ then any descomposition of $k$ must be of the form $T_N + a$ (since a descomposition with $n\neq N$ will be either too low or too high). That forces $a$ to be $k - T_N$ (wich is an integer between $1$ and $N+1$, both included, because $t_N < k \leq t_{N+1}$).

Comment: Prove it please.

Comment: Can you prove that there exists a unique consecutive integer sum for each integer?

Comment: This should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your known triangular numbers inside the limits you've established.
$$ t_6 = 21=1+2+3+4+5+6$$
$$ t_5 = 15=1+2+3+4+5$$
$$ t_4 = 10=1+2+3+4$$
$$ t_3 = 6=1+2+3$$
$$ t_2 = 3=1+2$$
$$ t_1 = 1=1$$

For the interceding integers, $$ t_n < Y < t_{n+1} $$
$$ Y = t_n + x_{0 \rightarrow n}, \text{ where }  x_{0 \rightarrow n}: 1 \leq x \leq n \in \rm I\!R$$

Additionally,
$$ t_n + ( n+1 ) =t_{n+1} $$

Each group of Y, existing between the triangle numbers, is the result of adding n + 1 integers, which occurs n times. 
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 +4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 91$$